# Why do I get an ImportError: Cannot import name 'gmap' in python?

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
```

These are my import codes to write a Bokeh program that reads the latitudes and longitudes information from a CSV file and plots the latitudes and longitudes with circles to visualize the institutions on google map. I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 if that matters.

This is the rest of my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('bc_adult_education.csv')

x=data['Latitude']
y=data['Longitude']
output_file("gmap.html")
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=50.748165, lng=-122.595148, map_type="roadmap", zoom=5)
p = gmap("API Key", map_options, title="BC")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=x,lon=y))

p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=5, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
show(p)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Is your error `cannot import gap` or `cannot import gmap`?

Comment: Yeah its gmap... sorry my computer autocorrected

Comment: Here is the full traceback

ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-a920b9c47a72> in <module>()

      4 from bokeh.io import output_file, show
      5 from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
----> 6 from bokeh.plotting import gmap
      7 
      8

Comment: Update your bokeh. It's probably out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Bokeh is too old. `gmap` was added in version `0.12.5`:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#release-0-12-15

Comment: Perfect thanks! I am now running into an error saying cannot import name 'Horizontal location'. Any ideas to this?